# Best way to guarantee correct Ajax calls parameter values

Tags: php, ajax, encryption

I am working on a website that requires some ajax calls in order to improve flexibility and performance. 
My ajax calls is for a ranking system. I need three input values to be processed with ajax (storeID, clientID, orderID). To submit an action with ajax, I want to make sure that the parameters values sent were not modified by users using web tools. So I was thinking of three different ways to guarantee that the information sent were not changed:

1. Send an extra value that is the encryption of all the data sent all together. So at the server side while processing ajax, I can re encrypt the data sent and see if the encryption result matches the encryption value sent.
2. Send all the data as one encrypted value. Then on the server while doing the ajax, I can decrypt the data and assign the values again.
3. Send only the orderID and its encryption then using method (1) verify that the orderID is not changed, and using the database query, fetch the two other information.

Here's my opinion on each of the three ways:

1. Consumes memory since I have to send orderID, clientID, storeID, encryptedID. Moreover, the information monitored in the ajax call will give people information about what happens when they rate an order.
2. I checked online for mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt but I've never used them. I saw that they produce a long string, but I prefer to keep my data sent short or look like the md5 encrypted data. Is there better methods ?
3. This is the elegant way, it looks straight forward but it needs some MySQL intervention, which could be time consuming especially when data grows in the future.

So which one do you think is better ? If you have more ways I appreciate if you share them here. Thank you

Example of scenario I want to avoid:
Clicking a button will submit a form using AJAX by passing the Product ID. A user go to the source code, and change the ID of the product from X to Y. Now the user clicks the button and the form was submitted and the product of ID Y was be affected. As you can see, the parameter values sent are not secured and can be modified. I am searching for a way to guarantee that the parameter values sent are correct and not modified.

**PS**: This question is not about CSRF handling.

Comment: Client side can never be 100% secured, whatever encryption algorithm you put on the client side you have to put either the module or key or both on client side which can easily be fetched and your request can easily be tampered.

Comment: It sounds like you want to prevent a user form editing something that the user is _not allowed_ to edit. So the user is only allowed to edit product `1` and `3` for example. If this is the case, then you need to check this server-side (which is the only secure way of doing it). But if you're worried about the user trying to edit `3` while he/she is on a form for `1`, why worry? The user can simple navigate to the form for `3` anyway...

Comment: The third solution looks standard and in fact the only one which is reasonable. Fetching two values from a DB shouldn't worry you : if it's slow, it means you're not doing it wrong and that can be solved.

Comment: If we understand your use case, you are just complicating thins, as stated by jofresco, this is solved with AUTHENTICATION+AUTORIZATION on the SERVER SIDE (as you stated, client can always tamper data)

Comment: @Mtorres yes but how to do this ? Authentication is having a session for the user. Autorization is the missing part. How can you verify that the data sent are correct.

Comment: @Amir if a user is not allowed to change `(storeID, clientID, orderID)` then why send that info to them at all just to have them send it back? Couldn't you store it in the session?

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes but as I mentioned somewhere in this page, having multiple pages opened at the same time will will keep overwriting the previous information, which I don't want this to happen.

Comment: @Amir it sounds like you just need to encrypt before sending and decrypt after receiving (if the user tampered then decryption will fail). hashing will not work because you don't have the originals in the session to compare the hash to

Comment: Amir, a simply way to do the authorization would be to remember which users (assuming cliendID) are allowed which storeID, orderID pair. You can put that in a database, then when you receive a petition, before handling it just check if its valid (you also can put a time out and create a cron job to delete expired petitions). This is basically what @jason_larke is doing (besides the encription part, but I really don't see the point in the use of encryption for this use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly simple way would be to `salt` a basic forward-only (i.e sha/md5 etc.) hash of the three parameters against a secret key kept on the server (and **never** exposed to users in any way).

Then, when you receive the request from the user you can simply replicate this forward-only hashing process to ensure that the data hasn't been tampered with, similar to how most sites implement authentication without having to store a plaintext copy of the user's password in their database.

For example:

```
define('SUPER_SECRET_KEY', 'foobar123'); // our 007 secret key to hash requests against

function generateToken($storeID, $clientID, $orderID) {
    return hash('sha256', SUPER_SECRET_KEY . "/{$storeID}/{$clientID}/{$orderID}");
}

function validateToken($token, $storeID, $clientID, $orderID) {
    return generateToken($storeID, $clientID, $orderID) === $token;
}
```

Now this is, as I said, a very basic starting point. Using a static `salt` value isn't going to be very effective, and you still leave yourself open to replay attacks (i.e someone spamming that same token/clientID/storeID/orderID combination over and over again).

One way to combat replay attacks is to generate a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) for each request to act as the `salt`.

Another super basic example using `nonces`, heavy pseudocode ahead:

```
function generateNonce() {
    return hash('sha512', mt_rand() . time()); // please make a more secure nonce generator than this :)
}

// We need a way to retrieve the nonce for a particular request:
function generateLookup($storeID, $clientID, $orderID) {
    return hash('sha256', "{$storeID}/{$clientID}/{$orderID}");
}

function generateToken($nonce, $storeID, $clientID, $orderID) {
    $lookup = generateLookup($storeID, $clientID, $orderID);

    // Store the $nonce and $lookup somewhere (i.e a database)
    $db->query("INSERT INTO ... (nonce,lookup,expired) VALUES ('$nonce','$lookup','N')");

    return hash('sha256', "{$nonce}/$storeID/$clientID/$orderID");
}

function validateToken($token, $storeID, $clientID, $orderID) {
    $lookup = generateLookup($storeID, $clientID, $orderID);
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT nonce FROM ... WHERE lookup = '$lookup' AND expired = 'N'"); // again, pseudocode for retrieving the nonce from the persistent store
    if (count($rows) !== 0) {
        $nonce = $rows[0]['nonce'];
        // expire the nonce (note: these database queries should be in a transaction)
        $db->query("UPDATE ... SET expired = 'Y' WHERE $lookup = '$lookup' AND nonce = '$nonce'");
        return generateToken($nonce, $storeID, $clientID, $orderID) === $token;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your basic workflow would become:

**On GET**

```
$data = // retrieve data
$token = generateToken(generateNonce(), $data['storeID'], $data['clientID'], $data['orderID']);

// output the $token value in a hidden field in your form
```

**On POST**

```
if (validateToken($_POST['token'], $_POST['storeID'], $_POST['clientID'], $_POST['orderID'])) {
    // All good
}
else {
    echo "Back, ye filthy hacker!";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Everyone is trying to lead you to these points:

On the server....

1. You know who the user is (auth).
2. You should define what that user can access  (ACL).
3. You should validate that the requested product both exists and is allowed to be accessed by the user.
4. If the user is allowed to make changes to the product, then it is, by definition, within their rights to make a change to X product, and if they do it with Y product information because they are messing around in the source, then that is on the user.
5. If this is shopping cart-related, then you should be ignoring all other data passed by the user (like, say, price) and load that product data by ID only.  So they cannot buy Y product at X product's price.  And then, if they enter in Y product's ID in Firebug, who cares?

And if you aren't doing 2 and 3, you're wasting your time completely on this idea.  Whatever you come up with will only be adding obscurity to your insecurity.

Comment: Amen @joefresco. I've just want to point that maybe ACL is not required, the generic term is authorization (which ACL is one method of doing it). Take a look at this fantastic [explanation from symfony web site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) (it's symfony related but the general concept is there)

Comment: @joefresco, yes, completly agree, they all answer complex things as asked by the OP, but they miss the fact that this is not necessary and wrong by design...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use encryption, you may use the Mcrypt functions with the Rijndael cipher. That gives you a block of 128 bits to play with.

Suppose your three IDs (storeID, clientID, orderID) are 32 bit each, you can pack those together with a 4 character string to form a 128 bit block. The string will be used to check the decrypted data later on.

```
$block = pack('a4LLL', 'MyID', $storeID, $clientID, $orderID);
```

Then create a random IV and encrypt the block:

```
$mod = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($mod));
$mySecretKey = 'LA72U/aLEOcDoN0rqtM5sehNNjd7TUSILiBgI8bej6o=';

mcrypt_generic_init($mod, base64_decode($mySecretKey), $iv);

$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($mod, $block);

mcrypt_generic_deinit($mod);
mcrypt_module_close($mod);
```

You'll need to encode the encrypted block and the IV before using them client side. Using base64 and swapping the / and + characters gives you a nice value that can be sent as a GET parameter:

```
$encodedBlock = substr(strtr(base64_encode($encrypted), '/+', '-_'), 0, -2);
$encodedIV = substr(strtr(base64_encode($iv), '/+', '-_'), 0, -2);
```

Later when those values are sent to your ajax scripts, just reverse the process:

```
$encrypted = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['block'], '-_', '/+') . '==');
$iv = base64_decode(strtr($_GET['iv'], '-_', '/+') . '==');
$mod = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

mcrypt_generic_init($mod, base64_decode($mySecretKey), $iv);

$block = mdecrypt_generic($mod, $encrypted);

mcrypt_generic_deinit($mod);
mcrypt_module_close($mod);

$data = unpack('a4str/Lstore/Lclient/Lorder', $block);

if ($data['str'] != 'MyID')
  throw new Exception('Something fishy is going on');
```

If all goes well $data will contain $data['store'], $data['client'] and $data['order'].

You may also pack a nonce value into the block in order to protect against replay attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I really do not think encryption helps you here.

It seems your worry here is an already logged in user fiddling with the request parameters (normal session security should keep users without a login out).

I think you just need to validate the request on the server side. You should be able to identify your user via session variables. The ajax service can then validate the request in the normal way.

Comment: The obviously have a session when logged in, so I have no prob identifying the user. But my problem is that if this person submit a form using ajax with POST method and parameters that could be changed, then how can I trust the data, it could be modified

Comment: May the serialize method helps you ? First of all you create a cookie and assign the serialize value to cookie, when you fire the ajax no need to pass the form value. In your action file (ajax.php) fetch form data from cookie and delete the ckookie data.

Comment: You know who the user is, you  sent him the screen in the first place, I do not see why you have any trouble validating the request on your server. Encryption really won't help as you will have to ship the key with the data.

Comment: @biswajitGhosh Serialize() doesn't really helps because the data sent is still human readable and can be modified by web tools.

Comment: @JamesAnderson I don't really understand you method. You mean assign the parameters in the session of the user ? If yes, than lets say that the user opened 2 pages (Page 1 and Page 2). Since Page 2 is the last opened page, therefore, the information of Page 2 will be stored. The problem is, what if the user switched to the Page 1 tab and wants to rank ? He/she won't be able because only Page 2(Last opened page) information are stored.

Comment: @Amir -- this is very confusing. The situation you describe has nothing to do with your original question. I forget about encryption and start again. If you define the problem (if it is indeed  a problem) clearly I think you will find normal server side validation is all you need.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Well said ! , he is totally confused and confusing us

Comment: Sorry people if I've confused you. I'll describe briefly again what I want: I want to make sure that parameters value sent using AJAX are not modified by the user. @JamesAnderson you method suggest to create a session to store the values, so the user has no access to it. My problem with this solution is that if a user opened several pages, the session will be overwritten each time and only the last opened page can be affected.

Comment: @biswajitGhosh you solution suggest to create a cookie containing the data serialized. My problem with this solution is that serialize doesn't encrypt the data, therefore the user can still edit them, and that's what I'm trying to avaoid.

Comment: @Amir the session is not necessarily overwritten. For example, if you send a randomly generated token to the form, as the key to an array that contains all of the relevant information, whenever they submit the form with the token, you can retrieve the settings attached to the form

Answer (score 2):

For security matters you need to keep things simple.

Here the simple fact is that any client side content **can** be altered.

So what you need is a **server side** check.

The server made the original form, and this form was set on page dedicated to one specific user. This form should have som CSRF tokens, ensuring that posted data comes from the page built by the server, not from another website, not from some automated script, etc.

So the first step is to ensure all your forms contains some tokens, and that all forms built by your server can check theses tokens for a certain amount of time and ensure the tokens match the user/form generated previously. That means something like a cache of forms on the server side, with some serious cleanup tasks on this cache, and you will also need to hanlde messages (in ajax here) for posted form containing outdated tokens (Sorry you've been waiting for too long). Some simplier approaches only use the user session to store anti-CSRF tokens, you need to find a solution that fits all your needs (anonymous forms, shared forms, multi-step forms, etc)

Once you've got an anti-CSRF token system it's easy to also store on the server side things that prevents user alteration of the form elements.
Things like your "id" could simply be stroed on the form cache and not even send to the client side. You could also store some signature of form elements, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my main problem isn't the CSRF, I've handled this by passing an auto generated key periodically changing. My primary problem is, if I want to affect a specific row in the database by passing an ID using ajax. How can I ensure that the user passes the real ID and haven't changed it. Thanks again, I'll clarify my question more

Comment: Re-read my answer. What I'm saying is that you could reuse your server-side anti-csrf system to store anti-form alteration data. So this given ID MUST be checked with the token to ensure it was the same ID sent to the user. You cannot prevent changes server side. The only thing you can do is test server side that the thing received are the things once sent.

Comment: so basically your are developing my first bullet (in my question body) ?

Comment: Amir, if you want to be sure of ID, do not send theses ID to the client, send a token and store theses IDs server side, with the user request's token you'll find back the IDs you need, no way for the user to alter ID, the user does not need the IDs, and you do not need complex client side manipulation which are by nature unsafe and alterable.

Answer (score 2):

You went for a hard way without reasons.

You should almost never force a link between a request from a browser and the following ones. The proper logic (a basis of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)) would be

- on request, send to the browser the information related to the orderID
- handle a modification request by the browser *without worrying about previous requests* : simply check using the database that the modification request is valid and consistent and in that case handle it

Fetching two values from a DB shouldn't worry you : if it's slow, it means you're not doing it wrong and that **can** be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is send an extra value generated from the sent values as a hash (like md5), then in server using the same algorithm just compare sent hash to generated with values and if it is equals then posted data is valid.

Lets supose you use a Javscript md5 library, just calculate the hash with:

```
hash=md5('sometext'+storeID+clientID+orderID);
```

then submit this hash with AJAX and finally in the server calculate it again and compare.

The only problem i see if the work is done on client side is that users can easily get hash algorithm, calculate it and send. I guess You'd use some obfuscation techniques.

Also can get generate a random number include it in md5 and send an additional parameter. This will generate a different hash every time.

Comment: This is what I am working on right now, but I believe there's a better one, because if you check stackoverflow and other website that use the same ajax concept, they just send very few data.

Comment: Oh! well, I think in this situation would choose to combine a hash with a simple enconding method, so will convert all ids in words (4 bytes for every id) and the hash as a checksum. Doing this, only one parameter would be sent with ajax call and this parameter would be 4 * number of ids bytes lenght plus checksum. Then in server would take the received bytes and then unpack and check. Also Javascript obfuscation would be recomended. Thus data transfer would be minimal and cant be understood easily.

Comment: I would appreciate if you develop more your solution in your answer, because I am interested in the conversion your talking about. So basically you mean that you want to put numbers next to each others and append a verification string at the end of the data ? can the numbers encoded, be decoded in the server ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Never trust the client. Anything can be modified, and it's also safer to assume that they will eventually be able to guess what you implemented server-side. So, what I would recommend, is only send information that lets you identify decisions made.

For example, if the form only applies to 1 product at a time, store the value server-side (in a `$SESSION` variable for example). When they submit the form, it can only apply to that product, and will only affect what they could do with the UI anyway.

If the clientID is specific to the user, store server-side, and don't send it to the client at all.

If they could change clients, or products with the UI anyway, then it doesn't matter whether they modify the script or not.

Since you already seem to have some sort of authentication mechanism, just work off of that, if they have permissions to do something, who cares if they hack the client to do it, if they could do it by the UI anyway. If they don't have permission, don't let them even access the information in the first place. Sure, obscuring data they shouldn't have in the first place may seem secure, but it's definitely not as secure as not sending data they shouldn't know in the first place, no matter how obfuscated you've made it.

Edit: following the comments on other answers, there are many ways to implement this, but here's one to get you thinking:

You can easily handle multiple forms open at once: use `mcrypt_create_iv` to generate a random token. Say, 20 characters in length. Store it in a session array

```
$formtoken = mcrypt_create_iv(20);
$_SESSION['infos'][$formtoken] = array($value,$anothervalue);
```

Then send `$formtoken` to the browser. Every time the browser submits via AJAX, send a new form token and delete data stored with the previous one, so it is no longer valid as a submission. The only info you need to send is the token, which the user can't manipulate, because it's generated every time they request a form, and is only valid for that form, and the other data they could manipulate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `http` isn't secure by any means. Therefore:

> Please use `https` to protect the communication between client and
>   server.

By using https, you for example **protect the user's session against being hijacked**.

In case the data transferred from client to server using ajax isn't sensible regarding privacy, I won't propose to encrypt it.

> Keep non-privacy related data non-ecrypted.

Using this strategy, no one might guess, that certain sensible (e.g. tracking) related data gets transferred in a hidden fashion. Transfering **non-privacy related data non-encrypted** won't compromise the **trust of your users**.

**Data coming from the client isn't secure**

Certainly, your server application can't trust data coming from a client. The client might be

- a legitimate user
- a legitimate user's trojan hijacked PC
- or data packets injected from a third party.

**Verify the client -> server --> client cycle**

To verify, that data from a client really comes from a client requires the client pass back some sever-provided data.

Suppose a client is allows to transfer certain values `V1, V2, ...` using `http`, which before got passed along to the server.

> If the request comes through normal direct clicks on browser links or
>   indirect ajax calls isn't relevant.

**Sign with a static server side secret**

Since the values `V1, V2, ..., Vn` come from the server, sign the values as coming from your server's application.

Sing using a server-side secret `TheSecret`, e.g. a significantly long value like so:

```
SignValue := md5( V1 + V2 + ... Vn + TheSecret )
```

Certainly, you might use other one-way hashes. For most practical cases, `md5` might be strong enough.

**Sign with a temporal server side secret**

Besides a constant secret `TheSecret`, you might wish to generate a new secret each day. `DailySecret` might be generated like so:

```
DailySecret := TheSecret  + md5( TheSecret + date( 'Ymd' ) )
SignValue := md5( V1 + V2 + ... Vn + DailySecret )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your design if your ajax is sending that much sensitive information.

But if you can't do that, you can also just hash the values on the server, and your ajax takes hashed values only.  If client changes the hash, it becomes invalid, so there you go.  That's a standard practice to prevent id manipulation.

Hope this helps.