# Securing an api PHP/JQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating an open source API using php and allowing the public to use it via jQuery AJAX GET.

I just need to know how I can make this secure.

For example, the users can call my php api on my server using jquery ajax like this:

```
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/api.php";
var variable = $("#variable").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  data: 'variable='+variable,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $("#resultarea").html('' + data + '');
  }
});
```

is there anything I need to do/Know for securing this API before presenting it to the public?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt your data before sending like answered here .. [Best way to guarantee correct Ajax calls parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749368/best-way-to-guarantee-correct-ajax-calls-parameter-values)

Hope it helps :)